# vue-router sets wrong parameter after reloading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have

```
// routes.js
{ path: '/posts', name: 'Posts', component: PostsView },
{
    path: '/post/:post_id',
    name: 'PostRead',
    component: PostReadView,
},
{
    path: '/post/cu/:post_id?',
    name: 'PostCreateUpdate',
    component: PostCreateUpdateView,
},
```

```
// PostCreateUpdate.vue
mounted: function() {
    if( this.$route.params.post_id ) {
        this.$store.dispatch('getPost', this.$route.params.post_id);
    }
},
```

When I access the PostCreateUpdate via router-link like this

`<router-link :to="{ name: 'PostCreateUpdate' }">Create</router-link>`

It works with no problems as I see the parameter in the Vue Devtools isn't set, but when I access the URL by reloading or hard coding the url `/post/cu/` the framework (I think) removes the trailing slash and treats `cu` as some `/post/` parameter, thus, loading `PostRead` with `post_id=cu` and giving me something I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to always declare your most restrictive URIs first. Order matters, because Vue Router will go through your routes, and pick the first one that matches.

Invert your `/post/:post_id` route and `/post/cu/:post_id?` one:

```js
// routes.js
{ path: '/posts', name: 'Posts', component: PostsView },
{
    path: '/post/cu/:post_id?',
    name: 'PostCreateUpdate',
    component: PostCreateUpdateView,
},
{
    path: '/post/:post_id',
    name: 'PostRead',
    component: PostReadView,
},
```